# is it possible to customize foreign key to use a regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql, activerecord

We have a simple item and order model.

```
orders(url)
items(title, orders_count)
```

Where "url" can be any URL from the web for e.g. http://amzn.to/aCKiXO.  What we would like to do is that if the user enters "/items/7" for the "url" then have it behave like a foreign key.  So something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => :url, :regex => /items/n, 
                    :counter_cache => true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :foreign_key => :url, :regex => /items/n, 
                    :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Is this possible?  We're on Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.9.3 and on Postgresql 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to add a [foreign key constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-fk.html) that does a regular expression match - or anything except simple equality. See the PostgreSQL [documentation on constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html).

What you *can* do is any of:

- Write a [constraint trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) in PL/PgSQL to enforce the constraint you want;
- Split out the part you want to add a constraint on using a regexp in the application, and define a foreign key constraint on a column containing only that part; or
- Use a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger to split the part of interest out in PL/PgSQL when the row is inserted and add the part of interest to a foreign key column that contains only that part. The app doesn't need to know about the duplication since the DB is taking care of it behind the scenes.

Comment: If you write a constraint trigger, be careful about concurrency issues. You may need to do explicit locking or update redundant data to prevent race conditions; or use only `SERIALIZABLE` transactions for automatic protection from the race conditions. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc.html